# Tips/tool required for writing fast in latex?

Tags: texstudio

In my institute writing assignments in LaTeX is mandatory. Most of my assignment text involve plenty of mathematical expressions and figures like $\lim, \log, \Theta, \bigoplus $ etc. and many more. I first solve my assignments using pen and paper, then write them on LaTeX. It takes me around $2$ hours to compete writing one page in LaTeX, and my assignments are generally $6-7$ pages, so I spend huge time just for typing my answers in LaTeX. I don't spend much time searching for mathematical figures in mathjax anymore, I am comfortable with mathjax, but typing those formats, then reviewing the pdf, change again after I see formatting mistakes, then again reviewing, then I want to change the view a bit for clearity of text etc.. all together I am spending huge time. I have also got a book on LaTeX, but due to very tight course schedule in my institution, I am not getting any time to read that book.  I also tried building a tool myself, where I type details in word doc or excel, and the tool automatically converts it to LaTeX formatting, but it's not full proof, and it requires regular maintenance as and when I include more and more symbols in my assignments.

Any tips, or any direction if any tool available for writing fast in LaTeX, will be of great help.

Comment: what people can do fast is very subjective so hard to answer. For example you imply that you can type an equation faster in Word than in tex, I find that surprising, do you choose symbols from the menu or by typing in the linear format? I'd expect the menu to be considerably slower and the linear format to be around the same?

Comment: https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/

Comment: Many editors have auto-completion features. I remember [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), for instance.

Comment: So this is about mathematics, right? (That probably should be in the title.) I don't think it's clear what it is that takes the most time for you. Is it looking up what LaTeX commands to use? Do you think it is possible that you are writing roundabout LaTeX that with more proficiency you would write more direct and succinct? In that case it could be worthwhile to add an example to the question, like "for example constructing this equation took me 40 minutes: ...".

Comment: @js bibra : The link you gave, is amazing, but it does not have details of step by step instructions for a novice. I wish I could set those up in my system.

Comment: @Jairo A. del Rio : I am using TeXstudio. It's taking a lot of time. My typing speed is also not good.

Comment: @ David Carlisle, @pst: When I type is ms word, I can directly see formatted text, but when writing in textstudio, I can only see latex version, and have to compile it to see pdf version, and find out mistakes. That's what is causing delay, alongwith my not so good typing speed.

Comment: just train yourself not to run latex all the time, you should be able to type a page or so without re-running.

Comment: The main point of the link js bibra posted is using a editor that has some latex support and can be easily customised.  Emacs+AuCTeX is another good combination in that direction, but there is alwasy a learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difficultly is mainly writing maths, indeed LyX, that specially in the math mode is nearly a WYSIWYG editor:

[image: mwe1]

If the difficultly is LaTeX code in general, another good option could be R Markdown in the Rstudio editor. No help to write math code here (no menus for symbols, etc.) but beside the simplicity of markdown, the math parts can be showed as popup windows, so it is also easy check the result without compiling.

[image: mwe2]